# How to execute sub commands while executing one main command through build.xml

Tags: linux, ant, command, build.xml, subcommand

I have been trying to execute a list of commands through the build.xml as below

```
 <target name="cmdTar">
 <sshexec host="192.168.**.**"
      username="****"
          password="****"
          trust="true"
      commandResource="Commands.txt"/>
</target>
```

### Commands.txt

```
sh tomcat/webapps/MyProject/WEB-INF/bin/./myproject console -j   
import Desktop/XMLFiles/Rule.xml
```

What my requirement is the first command is a terminal command in linux to open a required console(it is going well), the second command is a command which is to be executed with in that opened console (via first command). But my problem is second command is also treated as a normal terminal command like first command. I want it to be executed as my project console command. How can we tell the build script that 1st command is a terminal command and the 2nd command is is a my project console command ? Please  suggest me if any one know the soluton.